# How to show timer on iOS lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, timer, sdk

I have a timer app and I would like to display timer progress on lock screen just like native iOS timer app does.
Does Apple provides any SDK to implement this feature?
[image]

Comment: Apple does not provide any API for this. So there is no way you can do this.

Comment: @rckoenes too bad, anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: All timers in your app get stopped when your app goes to background / locked

Comment: You can do it in a today widget http://stackoverflow.com/a/28018773/2303865