# How to display current time zones in a UITableView Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, timer

I'm trying to create a Time Zone App that would display the current time with each second counting up, I'm able to display the seconds on the label but all the rows display the same time. I tried appending the time zones with the current time to an array but I can't figure out a way to update the array every second in order to display the current time[image].

As you can see in the picture I need the seconds, minutes , and hours to update accordantly.

Here is what I got so far.

Thanks

```
import UIKit



class TimeZoneViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    var timer: Timer?
    

    @IBOutlet weak var timeZoneTableView: UITableView!

    var zoneNameArray: [String] = ["Alpha Zone","Bravo Zone"]
    // var offSetArray:[Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var timeArray:[String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timeZoneTableView.delegate = self
        timeZoneTableView.dataSource = self
        // SupportedLocation.rowHeight = 69
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        createTimer()
        // createTimerTest()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return zoneNameArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = timeZoneTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimeZoneSegue",for: indexPath) as? TimeZoneTableViewCell  {
            //timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            
            print(timeArray.count)
            cell.timeZoneNameLbl.text = zoneNameArray[indexPath.row]
            //updateTimer()
            return cell
        }
        
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 125
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        // 1
        guard let visibleRowsIndexPaths = timeZoneTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
            return
        }
        
        for indexPath in visibleRowsIndexPaths {
            // 2
            if let cell = timeZoneTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TimeZoneTableViewCell {
                
                
                // cell.updateTime()
                //                // Time
                //                //Local Time
                let dateDate = Date()
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                //
                formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                
                let timeResults = formatter.string(from: dateDate)
                //  print("\(timeResults)")
                
                //Zulu Time
                
                let UTCDate = Date()
                let formatterUTC = DateFormatter()
                
                
                for offset in zoneNameArray{
                    
                    switch offset {
                    case "Alpha Zone":
                        // print("Alpha")
                        
                        formatterUTC.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+0")!
                        formatterUTC.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                        formatterUTC.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                        
                        
                        
                        let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatterUTC.string(from: UTCDate)
                        // cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = defaultTimeZoneStr
                        timeArray.append(defaultTimeZoneStr)
                        
                    case "Bravo Zone":
                        print("Bravo")
                        
                        formatterUTC.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+2")!
                        formatterUTC.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                        formatterUTC.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                        
                        
                        
                        let defaultTimeZoneStrBravo = formatterUTC.string(from: UTCDate)
                        // print("\(")l
                        
                        // cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = defaultTimeZoneStrBravo
                        timeArray.append(defaultTimeZoneStrBravo) // defaultTimeZoneStrBravo
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                    cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = timeArray[indexPath.row]
                    
                }
                
                
                
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    func createTimer() {
        // 1
        if timer == nil {
            // 2
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                                         target: self,
                                         selector: #selector(updateTimer),
                                         userInfo: nil,
                                         repeats: true)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the timer to the UILabel itself

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299018/2303865

Comment: I did not work, I was able to use the answer of that question to update the label but it only shows one Time Zone. how can I apply that to the TimeArray where all my timezones are ? @LeoDabus

Comment: You are probably using the same instance of the label

Comment: @Roger , I think I caught the bug. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I caught the bug. In `updateTimer()` function, you did calculate the latest time and append them to `timeArray`, but you are populating the cell with `cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = timeArray[indexPath.row]`, which means you are always using the first batch of calculated time, leaving the latest time untouched.

To fix it, you should clear `timeArray` **before** `for offset in zoneNameArray`.

**Updated**: This is the modified code snippet.

```swift
import UIKit


fileprivate let currentZoneName = "Current"
fileprivate let alphaZoneName = "Alpha Zone"
fileprivate let bravoZoneName = "Bravo Zone"

class TimeZoneViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    var timer: Timer?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timeZoneTableView: UITableView!

    var zoneNameArray: [String] = [currentZoneName, alphaZoneName, bravoZoneName]
    
    var zoneDict = [
        currentZoneName: TimeZone.current,
        alphaZoneName: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+0")!,
        bravoZoneName: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+2")!
    ]
    
    // var offSetArray:[Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var timeArray:[String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timeZoneTableView.delegate = self
        timeZoneTableView.dataSource = self
        // SupportedLocation.rowHeight = 69
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        createTimer()
        // createTimerTest()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return zoneNameArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = timeZoneTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimeZoneSegue",for: indexPath) as? TimeZoneTableViewCell  {
            //timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            
            print(timeArray.count)
            cell.timeZoneNameLbl.text = zoneNameArray[indexPath.row]
            //updateTimer()
            return cell
        }
        
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 125
    }
    
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        // 1
        guard let visibleRowsIndexPaths = timeZoneTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
            return
        }
        
        // cell.updateTime()
        //                // Time
        //                //Local Time
        let dateDate = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        //
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        
        let timeResults = formatter.string(from: dateDate)
        //  print("\(timeResults)")
        
        //Zulu Time
        
        let UTCDate = Date()
        let formatterUTC = DateFormatter()
        
        // remove all elements in timeArray, they are useless
        timeArray.removeAll()
        
        for offset in zoneNameArray{
            switch offset {
            case currentZoneName:
                formatterUTC.timeZone = zoneDict[currentZoneName]!
                formatterUTC.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                formatterUTC.dateFormat = "HH:MM:ss"
                
                let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatterUTC.string(from: UTCDate)
                // cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = defaultTimeZoneStr
                timeArray.append(defaultTimeZoneStr)
            case alphaZoneName:
                // print("Alpha")
                
                formatterUTC.timeZone = zoneDict[alphaZoneName]!
                formatterUTC.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                formatterUTC.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                
                let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatterUTC.string(from: UTCDate)
                // cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = defaultTimeZoneStr
                timeArray.append(defaultTimeZoneStr)
                
            case bravoZoneName:
                print("Bravo")
                
                formatterUTC.timeZone = zoneDict[bravoZoneName]!
                formatterUTC.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                formatterUTC.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                
                let defaultTimeZoneStrBravo = formatterUTC.string(from: UTCDate)
                // print("\(")l
                
                // cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = defaultTimeZoneStrBravo
                timeArray.append(defaultTimeZoneStrBravo) // defaultTimeZoneStrBravo
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        for indexPath in visibleRowsIndexPaths {
            // 2
            if let cell = timeZoneTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TimeZoneTableViewCell {
                cell.zoneTimeLbl.text = timeArray[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createTimer() {
        // 1
        if timer == nil {
            // 2
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                                         target: self,
                                         selector: #selector(updateTimer),
                                         userInfo: nil,
                                         repeats: true)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Other tips:

- You should not place `for offset in zoneNameArray` inside `for indexPath in visibleRowsIndexPaths`. Instead, put `for offset in zoneNameArray` **before** `for indexPath in visibleRowsIndexPaths`.
- Try to avoid creating instances frequently by sharing them (for example, make them as properties).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried clearing the timeArray by  timeArray.removeAll() but the app crashes with array out of bound. Im able to get the tableView populated with the correct time zones, I just need the seconds, minutes and hours in the table view to update live. Just like the clock App on the iPhone.

Comment: I actually ran smoothly.

Comment: can you post your code to compare it with mine ? Thanks

Comment: @Roger Updated with the `TimeZoneViewController`. I mainly changed the `updateTimer()` func, and added the current time zone as the first row. All the time labels on cells are updated correctly.

Comment: @Roger You're welcome. I'm glad it helped. Happy coding!